# pd.read_excel() memory usage

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file with an olap connection to an online data source. 
The file has about 25 sheets and takes up about 12 MB hard drive space.
When i attempt to open said file, my Spyder process end up taking up to 6 GB of physical memory and essentially freezes my pc.

the code I'm using is 
`df = pd.read_excel(xlsPath, sheetname = sth, header = 6)`

I'm not sure if the online data connection is causing trouble here but I don't quite understand why reading the excel file can take so much memory. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

Thanks

PC has 8GB Ram and and a low end i5 processor (2.00 GHz)

Comment: Ok, I figured this out in case anyone has the same issue. pandas seem to have trouble finding the end of Excel sheets especially for sheets with pivot tables. I worked around it by writing a VBA module to split Excel files into csv sheets, then pd.read_csv() them.

Comment: That's the fastest solution. Well done.